Failed to install: libraries.python3.vm using chocolatey
I was trying to install flare-vm from Mandiant's Github using the installation script, install.ps1. All packages installed but one, libraries.python3.vm. I keep getting an error and I'm not sure how to resolve it.
This is the error message I get when I run choco install libraries.python3.vm:
Installing the following packages:
libraries.python3.vm
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'ida.plugin.capa.vm 7.0.1 constraint: libraries.python3.vm (>= 0.0.0.20230927)'
Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-core.extension' that is compatible with 'dotnet-6.0-sdk-4xx 6.0.421 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.5.1)'.
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Failures
libraries.python3.vm - Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-core.extension' that is compatible with 'dotnet-6.0-sdk-4xx 6.0.421 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.5.1)'.
I manually deleted the chocolatey-core.extension package thinking there was an issue during installation, reinstalled it through the Windows PowerShell as an Administrator, and attempted to install the libraries.python3.vm again but I got the same error.

I met similar issue when I was installing FlareVM today:
Failures
 - libraries.python3.vm - 
Unable to resolve dependency 'kb2919355': 
Unable to find a version of 'kb2919355' that is compatible with 
'KB2999226 1.0.20161023 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)', 
'netfx-4.6.2 4.6.2 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)', 
'vcredist140 14.36.32532 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)', 
'visualstudio2017buildtools 15.8.0 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)'.

then I referred to the doc mentioned by @pauby, but found 'kb2919355' already installed.
PS C:\Windows\system32 > choco install kb2919355
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Installing the following packages:
kb2919355
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
KB2919355 v1.0.20160915 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

Then I ran this: choco install libraries.python3.vm --ignore-dependencies, but got another error:
ERROR : The term 'py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\ProgramData\_VM\vm.common\vm.common.psm1:1526 char:5
+     Invoke-Expression "py -3.10 -m pip install $package --disable-pip ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

which indicates python3.10 was not installed.
so I ran choco install python310 to install it and choco install libraries.python3.vm --ignore-dependencies again.
Luckly it worked finally:
PS C:\Windows\system32 > choco install libraries.python3.vm --ignore-dependencies
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Installing the following packages:
libraries.python3.vm
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading libraries.python3.vm 0.0.0.20240410... 100%

libraries.python3.vm v0.0.0.20240410
libraries.python3.vm package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
[+] Attempting to install Python3 module: acefile
        [+] Installed Python 3.10 module: acefile
[+] Attempting to install Python3 module: art
        [+] Installed Python 3.10 module: art
[+] Attempting to install Python3 module: binwalk
        [+] Installed Python 3.10 module: binwalk
...

The dependency unable to resolve in your log is different than mine, but guess you could follow same steps to see if it works.

Assuming your package dependencies are correct, the documentation already covers this issue.
If you have any issues in future, that is the first place to start looking.

Thanks for your reply. I have already seen this documentation and these are the issues


According to the first solution, i am to attempt to upgrade the affected packages but my issue is that all the packages involved in the error are the latest versions.


According to the second solution involving dependencies, i want to know if i force the libraries.python3.vm package to install, would there be any issues in the future?



You didn't mention that you had seen that documentation in your issue description. As part of any question you ask, you should always be specific about everything you've tried. While I'm not suggesting it was you who downvoted my answer, I feel that answering a question with something you have tried, that you didn't specify you had tried, is helpful. It doesn't encourage people to answer questions at all.
My suggestion is to use the Chocolatey Community Hub on Discord for community assistance. You'll get your questions answered there if you provide details of the libraries.python3.vm package.
